# How To Remove Whitespace on Merge

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have some code that takes 3 different PDF byte arrays and merges them.  This code works great.  The issue (some people) are having is that each PDF is considered to be a full page (if printed) even if there is only say 4 inches of content on it, thus leaving 7 inches of white space vertically.  Then the middle document gets put in and may or may not have vertical white space at the end of it.  Then the footer gets put on its own page as well.

Here is the code:

```
byte[] Bytes = rv.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out MimeType, out Encoding, out Extension, out StreamIDs, out Warnings);
List<byte[]> MergeSets = // This is filled prior to this code

// Append any other pages to this primary letter
if (MergeSets.Count > 0) {
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms);
  document.Open();
  PdfImportedPage page;
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Bytes); // read the generated primary Letter
  int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

  for (int i = 0; i < pages; ) {
    page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++i);
    copy.AddPage(page);
  } // foreach of the pages in the Cover Letter

  // Now append the merge sets
  foreach (byte[] ba in MergeSets) {
    reader = new PdfReader(ba);
    pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

    for (int i = 0; i < pages; ) {
      page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++i);
      copy.AddPage(page);
    } // foreach of the pages in the current merge set
  } // foreach of the sets of data

  document.Close();

  ServerSaved = SaveGeneratedLetter(ms.GetBuffer(), DateTime.Now.Year, hl.LetterName, SaveName);
} // if there is anything to merge
```

Is there a way when I am merging each page to clip/remove/erase the vertical white space at the end of each pdf so it appears as one seamless document?

> **UPDATE:**
> Here are some sample .pdf files I am trying to merge.

[header](http://1drv.ms/1B8VIVM), [body](http://1drv.ms/1B8VDBo), [footer](http://1drv.ms/1B8VPkb)

> **UPDATE 2: USING THE ANSWER:**
>
> I have converted @mkl's code to C# and here it is.
>
> The tool class:

```
public class PdfVeryDenseMergeTool {

  private Rectangle PageSize;
  private float TopMargin;
  private float BottomMargin;
  private float Gap;
  private Document Document = null;
  private PdfWriter Writer = null;
  private float YPosition = 0;

  public PdfVeryDenseMergeTool(Rectangle size, float top, float bottom, float gap) {
    this.PageSize = size;
    this.TopMargin = top;
    this.BottomMargin = bottom;
    this.Gap = gap;
  } // PdfVeryDenseMergeTool

  public void Merge(MemoryStream outputStream, List<PdfReader> inputs) {
    try {
      this.OpenDocument(outputStream);

      foreach (PdfReader reader in inputs) {
        this.Merge(reader);
      } // foreach of the PDF files to merge
    } finally {
      this.CloseDocument();
    } // try-catch-finally
  } // Merge

  public void OpenDocument(MemoryStream outputStream) {
    this.Document = new Document(PageSize, 36, 36, this.TopMargin, this.BottomMargin);
    this.Writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document, outputStream);

    this.Document.Open();
    this.NewPage();
  } // OpenDocument

  public void CloseDocument() {
    try {
      this.Document.Close();
    } finally {
      this.Document = null;
      this.Writer = null;
      this.YPosition = 0;
    } // try-finally
  } // CloseDocument

  public void NewPage() {
    this.Document.NewPage();
    this.YPosition = PageSize.GetTop(this.TopMargin);
  } // Merge

  public void Merge(PdfReader reader) {
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

    for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++) {
      this.Merge(reader, parser, pageIndex);
    } // foreach of the pages of the current PDF
  } // Merge

  public void Merge(PdfReader reader, PdfReaderContentParser parser, int pageIndex) {
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = Writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageIndex);
    PdfContentByte directContent = Writer.DirectContent;

    PageVerticalAnalyzer finder = parser.ProcessContent(pageIndex, new PageVerticalAnalyzer());

    if (finder.VerticalFlips.Count < 2)
      return;

    Rectangle pageSizeToImport = reader.GetPageSize(pageIndex);

    int startFlip = finder.VerticalFlips.Count - 1;
    bool first = true;

    while (startFlip > 0) {
      if (!first)
        this.NewPage();

      float freeSpace = this.YPosition - PageSize.GetBottom(BottomMargin);
      int endFlip = startFlip + 1;

      while ((endFlip > 1) && (finder.VerticalFlips[startFlip] - finder.VerticalFlips[endFlip - 2] < freeSpace))
        endFlip -= 2;

      if (endFlip < startFlip) {
        float height = finder.VerticalFlips[startFlip] - finder.VerticalFlips[endFlip];

        directContent.SaveState();
        directContent.Rectangle(0, this.YPosition - height, pageSizeToImport.Width, height);
        directContent.Clip();
        directContent.NewPath();

        this.Writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, this.YPosition - (finder.VerticalFlips[startFlip] - pageSizeToImport.Bottom));

        directContent.RestoreState();
        this.YPosition -= height + this.Gap;
        startFlip = endFlip - 1;
      } else if (!first) {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Page {0} content too large", pageIndex));
      } // if

      first = false;
    } // while
  } // Merge
} // PdfVeryDenseMergeTool
```

> The RenderListener class:
> **UPDATE 3:** FIXED 1 LINE OF CODE AND IT WORKS:  See comment in code

```
public class PageVerticalAnalyzer : IRenderListener {

  public PageVerticalAnalyzer() { }

  public List<float> VerticalFlips = new List<float>();

  public void AddVerticalUseSection(float from, float to) {
    if (to < from) {
      float temp = to;
      to = from;
      from = temp;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < VerticalFlips.Count; i++) {
      float flip = VerticalFlips[i];
      if (flip < from)
        continue;

      for (j = i; j < VerticalFlips.Count; j++) {
        flip = VerticalFlips[j];
        if (flip < to)
          continue;
        break;
      }
      break;
    } // foreach of the vertical flips

    bool fromOutsideInterval = i % 2 == 0;
    bool toOutsideInterval = j % 2 == 0;

    while (j-- > i)
      VerticalFlips.RemoveAt(j); // This was the problem line with just .Remove(j)
    if (toOutsideInterval)
      VerticalFlips.Insert(i, to);
    if (fromOutsideInterval)
      VerticalFlips.Insert(i, from);
  } // AddVerticalUseSection

  public void BeginTextBlock() { /* Do nothing */  }

  public void EndTextBlock() { /* Do nothing */ }

  public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    Matrix ctm = renderInfo.GetImageCTM();
    List<float> YCoords = new List<float>(4) { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
        Vector corner = new Vector(x, y, 1).Cross(ctm);
        YCoords[2 * x + y] = corner[Vector.I2];
      }
    }

    YCoords.Sort();
    AddVerticalUseSection(YCoords[0], YCoords[3]);
  } // RenderImage

  public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    LineSegment ascentLine = renderInfo.GetAscentLine();
    LineSegment descentLine = renderInfo.GetDescentLine();
    List<float> YCoords = new List<float>(4) {
      ascentLine.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2],
      ascentLine.GetEndPoint()[Vector.I2],
      descentLine.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2],
      descentLine.GetEndPoint()[Vector.I2],
    };

    YCoords.Sort();
    AddVerticalUseSection(YCoords[0], YCoords[3]);
  } // RenderText
} // PageVericalAnalyzer
```

> Code to gather files and run the tool:

```
public void TestMergeDocuments() {
  PdfVeryDenseMergeTool tool = new PdfVeryDenseMergeTool(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 18, 18, 10);
  List<byte[]> Files = new List<byte[]>();

  // Code to load each of the 3 files I need into this byte array list
  
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    List<PdfReader> files = new List<PdfReader>();

    foreach (byte[] ba in Files) {
      files.Add(new PdfReader(ba));
    } // foreach of the sets of data

    tool.Merge(ms, files);

    // Save the file using: ms.GetBuffer()
  } // using the memory stream
} // TestMergeDocuments
```

Comment: See [this answer for a start](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4084646/231316)

Comment: Also, not directly related but [you almost always want to use `ms.ToArray()` instead of `ms.GetBuffer()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119739/231316)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas, seems as if my next question is **how to grab the content** of a .pdf as is.  I know the `.GetTextFromPage` would be fine it there were no formatting, images or anything else.  But that does not help me.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28024276/1729265) may help, too.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, that is close.  I commented on that thread to see if I can be helped for my scenario.

Comment: @Grandizer, although we reference other posts for you too look at it is best to keep the discussion on this question only. In response to your comment over there, you say that you have a header, a footer and body content. However the unfortunate truth is **you do not have any of these**. Instead, you have something that _looks_, according to your own opinion, to be a header or a footer. Maybe the text is larger, maybe it is indented more, maybe a bold font is used. You are going to define your "header" and "footer" programmatically and perform a search based on that.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have updated **this** post based on questions from the other post.

Comment: @Grandizer I haven't had enough spare time today for this but I'll get back to it on Monday.

Comment: @Grandizer I hope the tool shown in my answer is of help.

Comment: @mkl I was not able to get to this today. Should be able to look at it tomorrow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The following sample tool has been implemented along the ideas of the tool `PdfDenseMergeTool` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024276/1729265) which the OP has commented to be* SO close to what *[he]* NEED*s. Just like `PdfDenseMergeTool` this tool here is implemented in Java/iText which I'm more at home with than C#/iTextSharp. As the OP [has already translated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010561/1729265) `PdfDenseMergeTool` to C#/iTextSharp, translating this tool here also should not be too great a problem.*

### PdfVeryDenseMergeTool

This tool similarly to [`PdfDenseMergeTool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024276/1729265) takes the page contents of pages from a number of `PdfReader` instances and tries to merge them densely, i.e. putting contents of multiple source pages onto a single target page if there is enough free space to do so. In contrast to that earlier tool, this tool even splits source page contents to allow for an even denser merge.

Just like that other tool the `PdfVeryDenseMergeTool` does not take vector graphics into account because the iText(Sharp) parsing API does only forward text and bitmap images

The `PdfVeryDenseMergeTool` splits source pages which do not completely fit onto a target page at a horizontal line which is not intersected by the bounding boxes of text glyphs or bitmap graphics.

The tool class:

> ```
> public class PdfVeryDenseMergeTool
> {
>     public PdfVeryDenseMergeTool(Rectangle size, float top, float bottom, float gap)
>     {
>         this.pageSize = size;
>         this.topMargin = top;
>         this.bottomMargin = bottom;
>         this.gap = gap;
>     }
>
>     public void merge(OutputStream outputStream, Iterable<PdfReader> inputs) throws DocumentException, IOException
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             openDocument(outputStream);
>             for (PdfReader reader: inputs)
>             {
>                 merge(reader);
>             }
>         }
>         finally
>         {
>             closeDocument();
>         }
>     }
>
>     void openDocument(OutputStream outputStream) throws DocumentException
>     {
>         final Document document = new Document(pageSize, 36, 36, topMargin, bottomMargin);
>         final PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
>         document.open();
>         this.document = document;
>         this.writer = writer;
>         newPage();
>     }
>
>     void closeDocument()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             document.close();
>         }
>         finally
>         {
>             this.document = null;
>             this.writer = null;
>             this.yPosition = 0;
>         }
>     }
>
>     void newPage()
>     {
>         document.newPage();
>         yPosition = pageSize.getTop(topMargin);
>     }
>
>     void merge(PdfReader reader) throws IOException
>     {
>         PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
>         for (int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
>         {
>             merge(reader, parser, page);
>         }
>     }
>
>     void merge(PdfReader reader, PdfReaderContentParser parser, int page) throws IOException
>     {
>         PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.getImportedPage(reader, page);
>         PdfContentByte directContent = writer.getDirectContent();
>
>         PageVerticalAnalyzer finder = parser.processContent(page, new PageVerticalAnalyzer());
>         if (finder.verticalFlips.size() < 2)
>             return;
>         Rectangle pageSizeToImport = reader.getPageSize(page);
>
>         int startFlip = finder.verticalFlips.size() - 1;
>         boolean first = true;
>         while (startFlip > 0)
>         {
>             if (!first)
>                 newPage();
>
>             float freeSpace = yPosition - pageSize.getBottom(bottomMargin);
>             int endFlip = startFlip + 1;
>             while ((endFlip > 1) && (finder.verticalFlips.get(startFlip) - finder.verticalFlips.get(endFlip - 2) < freeSpace))
>                 endFlip -=2;
>             if (endFlip < startFlip)
>             {
>                 float height = finder.verticalFlips.get(startFlip) - finder.verticalFlips.get(endFlip);
>
>                 directContent.saveState();
>                 directContent.rectangle(0, yPosition - height, pageSizeToImport.getWidth(), height);
>                 directContent.clip();
>                 directContent.newPath();
>
>                 writer.getDirectContent().addTemplate(importedPage, 0, yPosition - (finder.verticalFlips.get(startFlip) - pageSizeToImport.getBottom()));
>
>                 directContent.restoreState();
>                 yPosition -= height + gap;
>                 startFlip = endFlip - 1;
>             }
>             else if (!first) 
>                 throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Page %s content sections too large.", page));
>             first = false;
>         }
>     }
>
>     Document document = null;
>     PdfWriter writer = null;
>     float yPosition = 0; 
>
>     final Rectangle pageSize;
>     final float topMargin;
>     final float bottomMargin;
>     final float gap;
> }
> ```
>
> *([PdfVeryDenseMergeTool.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/PdfVeryDenseMergeTool.java))*

This tool makes use of a custom `RenderListener` for use with the iText parser API:

> ```
> public class PageVerticalAnalyzer implements RenderListener
> {
>     @Override
>     public void beginTextBlock() { }
>     @Override
>     public void endTextBlock() { }
>
>     /*
>      * @see RenderListener#renderText(TextRenderInfo)
>      */
>     @Override
>     public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
>     {
>         LineSegment ascentLine = renderInfo.getAscentLine();
>         LineSegment descentLine = renderInfo.getDescentLine();
>         float[] yCoords = new float[]{
>                 ascentLine.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I2),
>                 ascentLine.getEndPoint().get(Vector.I2),
>                 descentLine.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I2),
>                 descentLine.getEndPoint().get(Vector.I2)
>         };
>         Arrays.sort(yCoords);
>         addVerticalUseSection(yCoords[0], yCoords[3]);
>     }
>
>     /*
>      * @see RenderListener#renderImage(ImageRenderInfo)
>      */
>     @Override
>     public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
>     {
>         Matrix ctm = renderInfo.getImageCTM();
>         float[] yCoords = new float[4];
>         for (int x=0; x < 2; x++)
>             for (int y=0; y < 2; y++)
>             {
>                 Vector corner = new Vector(x, y, 1).cross(ctm);
>                 yCoords[2*x+y] = corner.get(Vector.I2);
>             }
>         Arrays.sort(yCoords);
>         addVerticalUseSection(yCoords[0], yCoords[3]);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * This method marks the given interval as used.
>      */
>     void addVerticalUseSection(float from, float to)
>     {
>         if (to < from)
>         {
>             float temp = to;
>             to = from;
>             from = temp;
>         }
>
>         int i=0, j=0;
>         for (; i<verticalFlips.size(); i++)
>         {
>             float flip = verticalFlips.get(i);
>             if (flip < from)
>                 continue;
>
>             for (j=i; j<verticalFlips.size(); j++)
>             {
>                 flip = verticalFlips.get(j);
>                 if (flip < to)
>                     continue;
>                 break;
>             }
>             break;
>         }
>         boolean fromOutsideInterval = i%2==0;
>         boolean toOutsideInterval = j%2==0;
>
>         while (j-- > i)
>             verticalFlips.remove(j);
>         if (toOutsideInterval)
>             verticalFlips.add(i, to);
>         if (fromOutsideInterval)
>             verticalFlips.add(i, from);
>     }
>
>     final List<Float> verticalFlips = new ArrayList<Float>();
> }
> ```
>
> *([PageVerticalAnalyzer.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/PageVerticalAnalyzer.java))*

It is used like this:

> ```
> PdfVeryDenseMergeTool tool = new PdfVeryDenseMergeTool(PageSize.A4, 18, 18, 5);
> tool.merge(output, inputs);
> ```
>
> *([VeryDenseMerging.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/VeryDenseMerging.java))*

Applied to the OP's sample documents

*Header.pdf*

[image: Header.pdf pages]

*Body.pdf*

[image: Body.pdf pages]

*Footer.pdf*

[image: Footer.pdf pages]

it generates

[image: A4 very dense merge result]

If one defines the target document page size to be A5 landscape:

> ```
> PdfVeryDenseMergeTool tool = new PdfVeryDenseMergeTool(new RectangleReadOnly(595,421), 18, 18, 5);
> tool.merge(output, inputs);
> ```
>
> *([VeryDenseMerging.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/VeryDenseMerging.java))*

it generates this:

[image: A5 very dense merge result]

***Beware!*** This is only a proof of concept and it does not consider all possibilities. E.g. the case of source or target pages with a non-trivial **Rotate** value is not properly handled. Thus, it is not ready for production use yet.

---

### Improvement in current (5.5.6 SNAPSHOT) iText version

The current iText development version towards 5.5.6 enhances the parser functionality to also signal vector graphics. Thus, I extended the `PageVerticalAnalyzer` to make use of this:

> ```
> public class PageVerticalAnalyzer implements ExtRenderListener
> {
>     @Override
>     public void beginTextBlock() { }
>     @Override
>     public void endTextBlock() { }
>     @Override
>     public void clipPath(int rule) { }
>     ...
>     static class SubPathSection
>     {
>         public SubPathSection(float x, float y, Matrix m)
>         {
>             float effectiveY = getTransformedY(x, y, m);
>             pathFromY = effectiveY;
>             pathToY = effectiveY;
>         }
>
>         void extendTo(float x, float y, Matrix m)
>         {
>             float effectiveY = getTransformedY(x, y, m);
>             if (effectiveY < pathFromY)
>                 pathFromY = effectiveY;
>             else if (effectiveY > pathToY)
>                 pathToY = effectiveY;
>         }
>
>         float getTransformedY(float x, float y, Matrix m)
>         {
>             return new Vector(x, y, 1).cross(m).get(Vector.I2);
>         }
>
>         float getFromY()
>         {
>             return pathFromY;
>         }
>
>         float getToY()
>         {
>             return pathToY;
>         }
>
>         private float pathFromY;
>         private float pathToY;
>     }
>
>     /*
>      * Beware: The implementation is not correct as it includes the control points of curves
>      * which may be far outside the actual curve.
>      * 
>      * @see ExtRenderListener#modifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo)
>      */
>     @Override
>     public void modifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo)
>     {
>         Matrix ctm = renderInfo.getCtm();
>         List<Float> segmentData = renderInfo.getSegmentData();
>
>         switch (renderInfo.getOperation())
>         {
>         case PathConstructionRenderInfo.MOVETO:
>             subPath = null;
>         case PathConstructionRenderInfo.LINETO:
>         case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_123:
>         case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_13:
>         case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CURVE_23:
>             for (int i = 0; i < segmentData.size()-1; i+=2)
>             {
>                 if (subPath == null)
>                 {
>                     subPath = new SubPathSection(segmentData.get(i), segmentData.get(i+1), ctm);
>                     path.add(subPath);
>                 }
>                 else
>                     subPath.extendTo(segmentData.get(i), segmentData.get(i+1), ctm);
>             }
>             break;
>         case PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT:
>             float x = segmentData.get(0);
>             float y = segmentData.get(1);
>             float w = segmentData.get(2);
>             float h = segmentData.get(3);
>             SubPathSection section = new SubPathSection(x, y, ctm);
>             section.extendTo(x+w, y, ctm);
>             section.extendTo(x, y+h, ctm);
>             section.extendTo(x+w, y+h, ctm);
>             path.add(section);
>         case PathConstructionRenderInfo.CLOSE:
>             subPath = null;
>             break;
>         default:
>         }
>     }
>
>     /*
>      * @see ExtRenderListener#renderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo)
>      */
>     @Override
>     public Path renderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo)
>     {
>         if (renderInfo.getOperation() != PathPaintingRenderInfo.NO_OP)
>         {
>             for (SubPathSection section : path)
>                 addVerticalUseSection(section.getFromY(), section.getToY());
>         }
>
>         path.clear();
>         subPath = null;
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     List<SubPathSection> path = new ArrayList<SubPathSection>();
>     SubPathSection subPath = null;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> *([PageVerticalAnalyzer.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/PageVerticalAnalyzer.java))*

A simple test ([VeryDenseMerging.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/VeryDenseMerging.java) method `testMergeOnlyGraphics`) merges these files

[image: circlesOnlyA.pdf]

[image: circlesOnlyB.pdf]

[image: circlesOnlyC.pdf]

[image: circlesOnlyD.pdf]

into this:

[image: circlesOnlyMerge-veryDense.pdf]

But once again ***beware:* this is a mere proof of concept. Especially `modifyPath()` needs to be improved, the implementation is not correct as it includes the control points of curves which may be far outside the actual curve.**

Comment: Thank you very much @mkl, that works for what I need it to do.  For future viewers of this page, I will be adding the C# code translated from the above to my above question.

Comment: Hey @mkl, I was back on this project and was noticing that at each new "page break" it is removing a line of text.  In certain instances, you can even see perhaps the bottom of a q or g.  I have been adjusting numbers here and there to see if I can figure it out but am having no luck.  I am wondering if there is a way to take care of this.  I was initially trying to add a buffer before and after each chunk so these lines are not truncated?

Comment: @Grandizer *at each new "page break" it is removing a line of text. In certain instances* - I just inspected the results of the merges based on your sample files and found no text lines missing. Please share sample files to reproduce the issue.

Comment: here is a [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=140D07AE327DA703!141531&authkey=!AA-mwXdJRG2JYm8&ithint=folder%2c) to the shared files.  Header, LargeBody & Footer then the Result in a FOTest.  Open up LargeBody and FOTest.  Scroll down to nearly the end where it says **21. Reports and Audit Rights**.  Compare the lines in the LargeBody section **20 Commercial Software** with the lines in the FOTest section 20.  The line that starts "Documentation are..." is cut off.  This is consistent with each NEW page break.  I also noticed the signature image is gone in this example as well.

Comment: I'll look into that. Might have to wait until after the Easter holidays.

Comment: understandable.  No worries.  Thanks

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the issue in Java but could not. Unfortunately I don't have a c# development environment set up at home. I'll try to reproduce it via rdp on my office computer. BTW, I saw in your code `// Save the file using: ms.GetBuffer()` - that is a bad idea, the buffer is bigger than the actual PDF. Use `ToArray` instead. This won't solve the problem at hands, though...

Comment: @Grandizer Back in Office today. I tested the merge tool using your very code and your source files. The result differs, though: especially there are no lines missing. The only immediate difference I see is that I am using iTextSharp 5.5.5 while you used 5.5.3.

Comment: well, I upgraded to 5.5.5 and no change. I even adjusted to your size, margins & gap from above. I still get what ends up being 1 missing line. I did notice when I copy the text from the newly generated .pdf file, it has everything PLUS three lines of text are duplicated. Ex. say that each Letter of the following is a single pdf line on its own. A B C D E from the original. Mine comes back SHOWING A B D E. Where C is right on the page break.  I copy the entire area between the two pages and it comes back as A B **C D B** C D E. Thanks for your time. Not sure what to do beyond this.

Comment: As mentioned before i cannot reproduce your issue. If you could simply pack a project reproducing the issue, we might get further.

Comment: I have gotten back to this project, mostly because the client is really wanting no white-space between documents.  So I have taken the time to create a console application that processes these files and merges them with your code.  [VS 2013 Source](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=140d07ae327da703!186502&authkey=!AABXwFbNL6dqRaE&ithint=file%2czip) Thanks in advance for checking this out.

Comment: Ok, I stepped through my Java program and your C# program simultaneously. I was surprised that unneeded vertical flips were not removed in your program. I looked it up in msdn, and the issue turned out to be: In `PageVerticalAnalyzer.addVerticalUseSection(float, float)` you translated `verticalFlips.remove(j)` as `VerticalFlips.Remove(j)` but it should have been `VerticalFlips.RemoveAt(j)`. In C# `List.Remove(x)` removes the first occurrence of `x` and `List.RemoveAt(x)` removes the xth element, in Java `List.remove(x)` removes the xth element for an int x and the first occurrence otherwise.

Comment: I have no idea why I did not get that problem when trying to reproduce the issue with C# here. Maybe I by accident looked at the Java result after running the C# code?

Comment: Aaah sweet!  That was the issue.  Thank you @mkl so much for the tons of effort you put into this for me.

Comment: You're welcome. As soon as the 5.5.6 iText updates find their way into iTextSharp, you may want to improve your code to also take vector graphics into account.

Comment: Will do, I noticed that when I check this post this morning.  Noticed no 5.5.6 yet.  But will keep an eye on it.