# How to add/project iTextSharp vectors

Tags: vector, itext

### The Question

The PDF toolkit iText(Sharp) has its [own vector type](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/itextsharp/ci/76fd2c9676884396c27dd6ef0cf653576c8f53a1/tree/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/Vector.cs#l65), implementing `Substract`, `Dot` product `Cross` product and `Multiply`, but I do not see an **addition** of vectors nor a **projection** of one vector onto antother.

Is there a simple way to do that?

### The context

I am implementing an `ITextExtractionStrategy` that **collects text into chunks** (`class MyTextChunk`) if they

- are on the same line `renderInfo.GetBaseline()`
- follow closely *to avoid concatenating texts from different columns in a table*
- and have the same height:  `renderInfo .GetAscentLine().GetStartPoint() .Subtract(renderInfo .GetDescentLine() .GetStartPoint()) .Length`

If I encounter a **single smaller superscript character** (i.e. above the base line, but not above the ascent line), I suppose this is to be a referred to later in the text and store it as `char referable`  in the chunk.

If the this `referable` is followed close enough by more text, this text must be included in the chunk. Therefore, I need to **extend the baseline till after the referable character**. So I thought writing something like

```
    public bool Append(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        ...
        if (thisIsAReferable) 
        {
            this.referable = infoText.Trim()[0];
            Vector offsetVector = baseVector.Multiply(
                baseVector.Dot(renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetEndPoint()
                .Subtract(this.baseline.GetStartPoint()))
                / baseVector.LengthSquared);
            this.baseline = new LineSegment(this.baseline.GetStartPoint(), 
                this.baseline.GetStartPoint().Add(offsetVector));
            ...                
            return true;
        }
        ...
    }
```

*Remark: The calculation of offsetVector is not yet verified.*

Comment: The `Vector` class was created for internal use, more specifically to do coordinate system calculations. What are *you* using them for? What is the use case behind this question?

Comment: In any case: we don't need addition or projection methods because in PDF, all the transformations of the coordinate system are expressed using a `Matrix`. Translations, rotations, scaling,... all these transformations are defined using 6 values (if you expected 9, think again: a PDF page is 2-dimensional, so 3 values of the matrix are predefined as `0`, `0`, `1`). Please consult ISO-32000-1 when in doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Vector` class is used to store the position of points on a PDF page when parsing a document. For instance: for each text snippet in the content stream of a PDF, we store several `LineSegment` objects: one that knows where the baseline starts and ends, one that knows where the ascent line starts and ends, one that knows where the descent line starts and ends. A `LineSegment` has two `Vector` elements, one for the start, one for the end.

The default coordinate system on a PDF page has an X axis that points to the right, and a Y axis that points upwards. The origin of the coordinate system depends on the value of the `MediaBox` (a mandatory property of each PDF page).

The default coordinate system can be changed using a transformation **(*)**. The transformation is defined using a matrix that looks like this:

[image]

The operator to change the coordinate system (the `cm` operator) requires 6 operands: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`. We don't need 9 operands in this matrix, because we are working in two dimensions.

If you want to define a translation, the `a` and `d` should be `1`; `b` and `c` should be `0`. You define the translation in the X direction by changing the value of `e`; in the Y direction by changing the value of `f`.

You can scale the coordinate system by defining `b`, `c`, `e` and `f` as `0` and change `a` to define the scaling factor in X direction, change `d` to define the scaling factor in Y direction. And so on. All of this is explained in great detail in ISO-32000-1.

I suggest that you perform translations (add) and other transformations using the `cross()` method and a matrix for which you define 6 elements.

We've never needed more methods for the `Vector` class because the parser always gives us the 6 operands of the `cm` operator, so we always have all the necessary elements to create a `Matrix` object.

**(*)** In PDF, we do not transform objects. We transform the coordinate system! I see that you live in Belgium. So do I, and I must admit that the concept of transforming the coordinate system seemed somewhat counter-intuitive because our schools and universities have taught us to transform objects, not coordinate systems.

Comment: So `Matrix offsetMatrix = new Matrix(offsetVector[Vector.I1], offsetVector[Vector.I2]);` ?