# iText java not parsing text properly from PDF/

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText Java API to extract text from a PDF.

```
String text =  PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,i);
```

Src PDF content:

1.2 SUBMITTALS

Generated Text:

SUBMITTALS
1.2

Extracted Text is split into 2 separate lines and order of the text is also messed up.

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Src pdf file link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/vc9it3c7856ejli/testPDF.pdf?dl=0

Target text file generated from iText - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ps2l9yz5ufuup01/test.txt?dl=0

But when I test with other PDF APIs like  PDFClown, OCROnline it is working as expected.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: reformat the code please

Comment: Also what does "Src PDF content - 1.2 SUBMITTALS Generated Text - SUBMITTALS 1.2" is from?

Comment: in Src PDF Link, open the PDF, you would see a section which starts with 1.2 SUBMITTALS  and in The Target Text File link - for the same section you would see SUBMITTALS in one line and 1.2 in a separate line. In my Java code I am just using "String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,i);" to extract the page content.

Comment: By the way, I am using 5.5.7 and tried with 5.5.10 as well. Same result.

Comment: I'm not really sure but maybe that the PDF coverter of iText make a different formatting from other pdf apis.

Comment: Does it make a difference if i use itext 7 version? Anyone has experienced this issue before? This seems to be a very common problem statement. Experts - please help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The cause

iText with its standard text extraction strategy extracts

[image: Screenshot]

as

```
SUBMITTALS
1.2
```

because the "1.2" actually is located (minutely) below the "SUBMITTALS":

```
q .75000 0 0 .75000 0 792 cm 
1 1 1 rg 0 0 816 -1056 re f 
q .32000 0 0 .32000 0 0 cm 
q 
...
q .20823 0 0 .20807 0 0 cm 
BT /F2 220 Tf 0 g 2340 -6628 Td(SUBMITTALS) Tj ET Q
q .20823 0 0 .20807 0 0 cm 
BT /F2 220 Tf 0 g 1440 -6634 Td(1.2) Tj ET Q
```

As you can see in this excerpt of the content drawing instructions from the PDF, the "1.2" is drawn at the scaled y coordinate -6634 while "SUBMITTALS" is drawn at -6628, i.e. "1.2" is drawn 6 scaled units below "SUBMITTALS".

This makes iText put it onto a separate following line.

#### A solution

You can use the [`HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy2`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy2.java) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33697745/1729265) instead of the default extraction strategy, cf. [TextExtraction.java test `testTestPDF`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/TextExtraction.java#L576), and get this output:

```
1.2 SUBMITTALS
```

(For details on the use of that strategy, confer the [answer mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33697745/1729265). [`HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy2`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy2.java) is the updated strategy from the section "UPDATE: Changes in LocationTextExtractionStrategy" of that answer.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation!!