# Itext Pdf merge . Seamless text merging

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to merge two pdf with content also being merged in single pdf. If content is overflowing it should add new page to it.

Challenge is the text should flow seamlessely.

I am trying to merge two pages of pdf and one of the text line is being cut from between. It's random based on content.

I am using text margin finder to find the remaining height of page.

Is there other way than textmarginfinder?

Comment: You are looking for something like what is shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29078954/1729265)?

Comment: Thanks for answer .which version of itext supports PageVerticalAnalyzer(). what is the maven dependency which I can use for same

Comment: Your answer talk about C#.I am using java so needed help on Java side.Thanks in advance

Comment: *Your answer talk about C#* - if you had read the answer, you would have seen that the code presented is java code.

Comment: *which version of itext supports PageVerticalAnalyzer()* - if you had read the answer, you would have seen that it includes an edit which improves the `PageVerticalAnalyzer` using features introduced in itext 5.5.6. If you prefer itext 7, you'll find the ported `PageVerticalAnalyzer` in the samples main sources.