# Concatenate 2 different pdf with or without PdfCopy class of Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to concatenate two different PDF files in a java project.

I've read in others posts that the best way is to use Itext class "PdfCopy", but the strange thing is that there isn't in my project even though I have the 7.0.6 of Itext in the pom and a commercial license.

Is there an explanation or another way to solve this task without using Itext or others external libraries?
Thank you

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: *I've read in others posts that the best way is to use Itext class "PdfCopy"* - that recommendation refers to itext up to version 5.x. itext 7.x is a major re-design of the whole api. In particular the functionality of the `PdfCopy` classes had been moved. Try `PdfDocument.copyPagesTo` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read in others posts that the best way is to use Itext class "PdfCopy"

That recommendation refers to iText up to version 5.x. iText 7.x is a major re-design of the whole iText api. In particular the functionality of the `Pdf*Copy*` classes had been moved. Try `PdfDocument.copyPagesTo` instead.

I.e. if you have loaded your source documents into `PdfDocument` instances `doc1` and `doc2` and have another, writable `PdfDocument` instance `dest` you want to copy those source documents into, simply do:

```
doc1.copyPagesTo(1, doc1.getNumberOfPages(), dest);
doc2.copyPagesTo(1, doc2.getNumberOfPages(), dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this as well:

[Is it possible to merger several pdfs using iText7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589413/is-it-possible-to-merger-several-pdfs-using-itext7)

Another library that can be used is PDFBox, sample below"

https://www.tutorialkart.com/pdfbox/pdfbox-merge-multiple-pdfs/