# Generate one pdf document with multiple pages converting from html using IText 7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm working with `IText 7`, I've been able to get one html page and generate a pdf for that page, but I need to generate one pdf document from multiple html pages and separated by pages. For example: I have `Page1.html`, `Page2.html` and `Page3.html`. I will need a pdf document with 3 pages, the first page with the content of `Page1.html`, second page with the content of `Page2.html` and like that...

This is the code I have and it's working for one html page:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();              
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfRoot, new WriterProperties().SetFullCompressionMode(true));
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new HeaderPdfEventHandler());
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlContent, pdfDocument, properties);
```

Is it possible to loop against the multiple html pages, add a new page to the PdfDocument for every html page and then have only one pdf generated with one page per html page?

**UPDATE**

I've been following [this](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/how-parse-multiple-html-files-one-pdf) example and trying to translate it from Java to C#, I'm trying to use `PdfMerger` and loop around the html pages... but I'm receiving the Exception `Cannot access a closed stream`, on this line:

```
temp = new PdfDocument(
                    new PdfReader(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(baos), rp));
```

It looks like is related to the `ByteArrayOutputStream baos` instance. Any suggestions? This is my current code:

```
foreach (var html in htmlList)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, temp, properties);              
    ReaderProperties rp = new ReaderProperties();
    temp = new PdfDocument(
        new PdfReader(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(baos), rp));
    merger.Merge(temp, 1, temp.GetNumberOfPages());
    temp.Close();
}
pdfDocument.Close();
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to loop against the multiple html pages"* - have you tried to create that loop? In which way did it fail? (Because indeed, it should be possible.)

Comment: The best solution is to generate those documents in memory and use `PdfMerger` to merge them into a single fat file

Comment: @mkl I've updated my question, I'm trying to do it that way but I'm receiving an Exception

Comment: @AlexeySubach Thanks for your suggestion, I'm trying to use `PdfMerger` but still hasn't been able to make it work, I've updated my question, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `RandomAccessSourceFactory` and passing there a closed stream which you wrote a PDF document into. `RandomAccessSourceFactory` expects an input stream instead that is ready to be read.

First of all you should use `MemoryStream` which is native to .NET world. `ByteArrayOutputStream` is the class that was ported from Java for internal purposes (although it extends `MemoryStream` as well). Secondly, you don't have to use `RandomAccessSourceFactory` - there is a simpler way.

You can create a new `MemoryStream` instance from the bytes of the `MemoryStream` that you used to create a temporary PDF with the following line:

```
baos = new MemoryStream(baos.ToArray());
```

As an additional remark, it's better to close `PdfMerger` instance directly instead of closing the document - closing `PdfMerger` closes the underlying document as well.

All in all, we get the following code that works:

```
foreach (var html in htmlList)
{
    MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
    PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, temp, properties);              
    ReaderProperties rp = new ReaderProperties();
    baos = new MemoryStream(baos.ToArray());
    temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(baos, rp));
    pdfMerger.Merge(temp, 1, temp.GetNumberOfPages());
    temp.Close();
}
pdfMerger.Close();
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 5 more times, thanks!!! Been struggling for a while with this...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not so succinctly. I use "using". [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40594055/6393097)

```
private byte[] CreatePDF(string html)
    {
        byte[] binData;

        using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
            {
                //Create one pdf document
                using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                {                        
                    pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    //Create one pdf merger
                    var pdfMerger = new PdfMerger(pdfDoc);
                    //Create two identical pdfs
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        using (var newStream = new MemoryStream(CreateDocument(html)))
                        {
                            ReaderProperties rp = new ReaderProperties();
                            using (var newPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(newStream, rp)))
                            {
                                pdfMerger.Merge(newPdf, 1, newPdf.GetNumberOfPages());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                binData = workStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return binData;
    }
```

Create pdf

```
private byte[] CreateDocument(string html)
    {
        byte[] binData;

        using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
            {
                using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                {
                    pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4.Rotate());

                    ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
                    using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfDoc, props))
                    {                            
                    }
                }
                binData = workStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return binData;
    }
```