# How to split a PDF file anywhere on the page?

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

How to split PDF file in the middle of any page?

In the text on one of the pages there is an "@placeholder", where I want to split the PDF at the place where it appears.

[image]

It is possible with iText or PDFBox? Or some other library?

Comment: You are aware that a PDF can be "painted" in any order - there is no requirement to start at the top and end at the bottom?

Comment: Unfortunately I know. I need to create a mechanism that will find "@placeholder" in a PDF file (containing tables, text, images, etc.), and will divide the document exactly here. All the split examples I've found breaks dokument on whole pages.

Comment: In PDFBox you could duplicate the page and create a cropbox that goes to the appropriate locations.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but first I have to find the appropriate locations. So how to find location of word in file?

Comment: You can find an example how to split pages using iText in my `PdfVeryDenseMergeTool` example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29078954/1729265). Also you can see there how split positions can be found using a render listener. In  your case you need a text extraction strategy (which is a special render listener, one only interested in text commands) to find the placeholder position.

Comment: In PDFBox you'd have to create the detection mechanism yourself, see the PrintTextLocations.java example. You'd know the location of each character of "@placeholder" and would have to recognise that you found the whole word.

Comment: @i_p *"How to split PDF file in the middle of any page"* - by the way, does this imply your document may have more pages?

Comment: @mkl yes, place to cut can be on first, second or other page