# How to find all occurrences of specific text in a PDF and insert a page break above?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a tricky requirement with a PDF

I need to search my pdf for a specific string - Property Number:

Each time this is found, I need to add a page break ABOVE

I have access to both IText and Spire.PDF, I am looking at IText first

I have established from other posts here that I need to use a PDF Stamper

The logic below adds a new page which does work

However, in my case, I just need a page break not a blank page

```
var newFile = @"c:\temp\full.pdf";
var dest = @"c:\temp\dest.pdf";
var reader = new PdfReader(newFile);
if (File.Exists(dest))
{
  File.Delete(dest);
}

var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.CreateNew));
var total = reader.NumberOfPages + 1;
for (var pageNumber = total; pageNumber > 0; pageNumber--)
{
  var pageContent = reader.GetPageContent(pageNumber);
  stamper.InsertPage(pageNumber, PageSize.A4);
}

stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
```

The picture below shows an example, so this would actually be 3 pages, the existing page, a new page break inserted above the first occurrence of Property Number:

Another page break is needed above the second occurrence

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say you *need to add a page break ABOVE*? Remember that PDF is a format where each page is created on a separate canvas, there are no *page breaks* to simply insert somewhere. Most likely you will have to split the contents of that single page into two (our more) pages which can be an interesting task, in particular if you happen to have header, footer, or background material to take care of.

Comment: Ah that's going to be fun then! I don't think I have page headers and footers is there a way to get the whole PDF in a single canvas then write a new PDF with 1 canvas per invoice? The screenshot above would generate 3 pages

Comment: In that case you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29078954/1729265). The `PdfVeryDenseMergeTool` therein splits page content to implement a merge tool that doesn't leave empty gaps. You can make use of the code in there that draws part of a source page on a target page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer shares a proof-of-concept for *finding all occurrences of specific text in a PDF and inserting a page break above* using iText and Java. It should not be too difficult to port it to iTextSharp and C#.

Furthermore, for production use some extra code has to be added as currently the code makes some assumptions, it e.g. assumes non-rotated pages. Furthermore it does not handle annotations at all.

The task actually is a combination of two tasks, the *finding* and the *inserting page breaks*, thus we need

1. an extraction strategy for locations of some custom text and
2. a tool cutting pages.

#### SearchTextLocationExtractionStrategy

To extract the locations of custom text, we extend the iText `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` to also allow to extract the positions of a custom text text string, actually of matches of a regular expression:

```
public class SearchTextLocationExtractionStrategy extends LocationTextExtractionStrategy {
    public SearchTextLocationExtractionStrategy(Pattern pattern) {
        super(new TextChunkLocationStrategy() {
            public TextChunkLocation createLocation(TextRenderInfo renderInfo, LineSegment baseline) {
                // while baseLine has been changed to not neutralize
                // effects of rise, ascentLine and descentLine explicitly
                // have not: We want the actual positions.
                return new AscentDescentTextChunkLocation(baseline, renderInfo.getAscentLine(),
                        renderInfo.getDescentLine(), renderInfo.getSingleSpaceWidth());
            }
        });
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    static Field locationalResultField = null;
    static Method filterTextChunksMethod = null;
    static Method startsWithSpaceMethod = null;
    static Method endsWithSpaceMethod = null;
    static Field textChunkTextField = null;
    static Method textChunkSameLineMethod = null;
    static {
        try {
            locationalResultField = LocationTextExtractionStrategy.class.getDeclaredField("locationalResult");
            locationalResultField.setAccessible(true);
            filterTextChunksMethod = LocationTextExtractionStrategy.class.getDeclaredMethod("filterTextChunks",
                    List.class, TextChunkFilter.class);
            filterTextChunksMethod.setAccessible(true);
            startsWithSpaceMethod = LocationTextExtractionStrategy.class.getDeclaredMethod("startsWithSpace",
                    String.class);
            startsWithSpaceMethod.setAccessible(true);
            endsWithSpaceMethod = LocationTextExtractionStrategy.class.getDeclaredMethod("endsWithSpace", String.class);
            endsWithSpaceMethod.setAccessible(true);
            textChunkTextField = TextChunk.class.getDeclaredField("text");
            textChunkTextField.setAccessible(true);
            textChunkSameLineMethod = TextChunk.class.getDeclaredMethod("sameLine", TextChunk.class);
            textChunkSameLineMethod.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Collection<TextRectangle> getLocations(TextChunkFilter chunkFilter) {
        Collection<TextRectangle> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            List<TextChunk> filteredTextChunks = (List<TextChunk>) filterTextChunksMethod.invoke(this,
                    locationalResultField.get(this), chunkFilter);
            Collections.sort(filteredTextChunks);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            List<AscentDescentTextChunkLocation> locations = new ArrayList<>();
            TextChunk lastChunk = null;
            for (TextChunk chunk : filteredTextChunks) {
                String chunkText = (String) textChunkTextField.get(chunk);
                if (lastChunk == null) {
                    // Nothing to compare with at the end
                } else if ((boolean) textChunkSameLineMethod.invoke(chunk, lastChunk)) {
                    // we only insert a blank space if the trailing character of the previous string
                    // wasn't a space,
                    // and the leading character of the current string isn't a space
                    if (isChunkAtWordBoundary(chunk, lastChunk)
                            && !((boolean) startsWithSpaceMethod.invoke(this, chunkText))
                            && !((boolean) endsWithSpaceMethod.invoke(this, chunkText))) {
                        sb.append(' ');
                        LineSegment spaceBaseLine = new LineSegment(lastChunk.getEndLocation(),
                                chunk.getStartLocation());
                        locations.add(new AscentDescentTextChunkLocation(spaceBaseLine, spaceBaseLine, spaceBaseLine,
                                chunk.getCharSpaceWidth()));
                    }
                } else {
                    assert sb.length() == locations.size();
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sb);
                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        int i = matcher.start();
                        Vector baseStart = locations.get(i).getStartLocation();
                        TextRectangle textRectangle = new TextRectangle(matcher.group(), baseStart.get(Vector.I1),
                                baseStart.get(Vector.I2));
                        for (; i < matcher.end(); i++) {
                            AscentDescentTextChunkLocation location = locations.get(i);
                            textRectangle.add(location.getAscentLine().getBoundingRectange());
                            textRectangle.add(location.getDescentLine().getBoundingRectange());
                        }

                        result.add(textRectangle);
                    }

                    sb.setLength(0);
                    locations.clear();
                }
                sb.append(chunkText);
                locations.add((AscentDescentTextChunkLocation) chunk.getLocation());
                lastChunk = chunk;
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        for (TextRenderInfo info : renderInfo.getCharacterRenderInfos())
            super.renderText(info);
    }

    public static class AscentDescentTextChunkLocation extends TextChunkLocationDefaultImp {
        public AscentDescentTextChunkLocation(LineSegment baseLine, LineSegment ascentLine, LineSegment descentLine,
                float charSpaceWidth) {
            super(baseLine.getStartPoint(), baseLine.getEndPoint(), charSpaceWidth);
            this.ascentLine = ascentLine;
            this.descentLine = descentLine;
        }

        public LineSegment getAscentLine() {
            return ascentLine;
        }

        public LineSegment getDescentLine() {
            return descentLine;
        }

        final LineSegment ascentLine;
        final LineSegment descentLine;
    }

    public class TextRectangle extends Rectangle2D.Float {
        public TextRectangle(final String text, final float xStart, final float yStart) {
            super(xStart, yStart, 0, 0);
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        final String text;
    }

    final Pattern pattern;
}
```

*([SearchTextLocationExtractionStrategy.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/SearchTextLocationExtractionStrategy.java#L31))*

As some necessary members of the base class are private or package private, we have to use reflection to extract them.

#### AbstractPdfPageSplittingTool

The page splitting functionality of this tool has been extracted from the `PdfVeryDenseMergeTool` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29078954/1729265). Furthermore, it is abstract to allow custom positions for page breaks.

```
public abstract class AbstractPdfPageSplittingTool {
    public AbstractPdfPageSplittingTool(Rectangle size, float top) {
        this.pageSize = size;
        this.topMargin = top;
    }

    public void split(OutputStream outputStream, PdfReader... inputs) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        try {
            openDocument(outputStream);
            for (PdfReader reader : inputs) {
                split(reader);
            }
        } finally {
            closeDocument();
        }
    }

    void openDocument(OutputStream outputStream) throws DocumentException {
        final Document document = new Document(pageSize, 36, 36, topMargin, 36);
        final PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        this.document = document;
        this.writer = writer;
        newPage();
    }

    void closeDocument() {
        try {
            document.close();
        } finally {
            this.document = null;
            this.writer = null;
            this.yPosition = 0;
        }
    }

    void newPage() {
        document.newPage();
        yPosition = pageSize.getTop(topMargin);
    }

    void split(PdfReader reader) throws IOException {
        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
            split(reader, page);
        }
    }

    void split(PdfReader reader, int page) throws IOException
    {
        PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.getImportedPage(reader, page);
        PdfContentByte directContent = writer.getDirectContent();
        yPosition = pageSize.getTop();

        Rectangle pageSizeToImport = reader.getPageSize(page);
        float[] borderPositions = determineSplitPositions(reader, page);
        if (borderPositions == null || borderPositions.length < 2)
            return;

        for (int borderIndex = 0; borderIndex + 1 < borderPositions.length; borderIndex++) {
            float height = borderPositions[borderIndex] - borderPositions[borderIndex + 1];
            if (height <= 0)
                continue;

            directContent.saveState();
            directContent.rectangle(0, yPosition - height, pageSizeToImport.getWidth(), height);
            directContent.clip();
            directContent.newPath();

            writer.getDirectContent().addTemplate(importedPage, 0, yPosition - (borderPositions[borderIndex] - pageSizeToImport.getBottom()));

            directContent.restoreState();
            newPage();
        }
    }

    protected abstract float[] determineSplitPositions(PdfReader reader, int page);

    Document document = null;
    PdfWriter writer = null;
    float yPosition = 0;

    final Rectangle pageSize;
    final float topMargin;
}
```

*([AbstractPdfPageSplittingTool.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/AbstractPdfPageSplittingTool.java#L31))*

#### Usage in concert

To implement the task of the OP:

> I need to search my pdf for a specific string - Property Number:
>
> Each time this is found, I need to add a page break ABOVE

one can use the classes above like this:

```
AbstractPdfPageSplittingTool tool = new AbstractPdfPageSplittingTool(PageSize.A4, 36) {
    @Override
    protected float[] determineSplitPositions(PdfReader reader, int page) {
        Collection<TextRectangle> locations = Collections.emptyList();
        try {
            PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
            SearchTextLocationExtractionStrategy strategy = new SearchTextLocationExtractionStrategy(
                    Pattern.compile("Property Number"));
            parser.processContent(page, strategy, Collections.emptyMap()).getResultantText();
            locations = strategy.getLocations(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Float> borders = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TextRectangle rectangle : locations)
        {
            borders.add((float)rectangle.getMaxY());
        }

        Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(page);
        borders.add(pageSize.getTop());
        borders.add(pageSize.getBottom());
        Collections.sort(borders, Collections.reverseOrder());

        float[] result = new float[borders.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < result.length; i++)
            result[i] = borders.get(i);
        return result;
    }
};

tool.split(new FileOutputStream(RESULT), new PdfReader(SOURCE));
```

*([SplitPages.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/SplitPages.java#L88) test method `testSplitDocumentAboveAngestellter`)*