# flying saucer pdf + itextpdf: how to append text to the last page in existing pdf file?

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer, itextpdf

I have to export several thousands html pages from the knowledge base to the pdf file. I'm using flying saucer library (because it knows how to correctly render html+css), which used itextpdf under the hood for pdf manipulation.

The problem is that for the huge amount of html documents our server fails with OOM error. It happens because flying saucer renders content before pdf creation, and this is very expensive operation.

I split export pages into "buckets", and just append them to the result file (as suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQPDF#How_can_I_print_multiple_pages_on_to_one_PDF,_if_they_come_from_multiple_documents?)). But the problem is that each new "bucket" starts from the new page, even if there are enough space on the last page of previous bucket.

So instead of having this:

```
Page
---------------------------
| last row of N-1th bucket|
| first row of Nth bucket |
|.........................|
|_________________________|
```

I have this:

```
Page
---------------------------
| last row of N-1th bucket|
|                         |
|                         |
|_________________________|

Page
---------------------------
| first row of Nth bucket |
|.........................|
|.........................|
|_________________________|
```

I found related thread - [ITextSharp - merge two pdfs in a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084157/itextsharp-merge-two-pdfs-in-a-single-page), but maybe there is a way to append content to the last page during pfd creation?

Any help is highly appreciated. I also tried to find some related example on http://itextpdf.com/sandbox, but without any luck.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you'd use [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker) (which also supports XHTML + CSS), we'd be able to help you, but you're using Flying Saucer which is a tool developed by people who aren't affiliated to iText Group in any way, so you'll have to hope that those people provide support on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use Flying Saucer b/c it renders html correctly with specific styles. This is highest priority for our customers. I'll give a try to XML Worker and see how it handles it.

Comment: btw how does it handle huge html files with thousands pages? as I mentioned in my question, Flying Saucer "renders" all content using different graphics tools, and then "copies" it to pdf (well, that's high level of course). That rendered context consumes a lot of space. How does XML Worker work? Won't I experience the same problems on a huge files (thousands of html pages)? Or did you mean that XML Worker just allows to append content to the last page?

Comment: It all depends on how you use XML Worker. The best way is to allow the document to flush finished pages as soon as they are done. Obviously, this won't work if your HTML consists of a large `<table>` with thousands of rows, but if your HTML is a sequence of independent blocks of content, then it will work adequately.

Comment: Can it handle html documents with links? So for example there is link at the beginning of the huge html document to its last page (somewhere at the end of the document). Does XML Worker handles such links correctly? Will result pdf file contain correct links?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem for my case, so posting the answer if someone is interested.

Problem was solved by "tweaking" flying-saucer library - here the [pull request with my changes](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/pull/77). Another positive side effect is passing a doc listener allows to track actual page rendering progress, which may be useful for visualisation of long-running processes.